# I need user input to point from one dataframe to another and display a column from the second dataframe-python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes:

1. state abbreviations and states.
   [image]
2. state names and all the national parks in each state. This is not the whole dataframe.
   [image]

I need to search for a user input in the state dataframe, in this case the state abbreviation, then take the adjacent value, the full name and use that to display the correct column from the parks dataframe.   I am sure this could be easier if they were one dataframe, but I could not figure a way to do that and keep all of the functionality; I want to be able to display the state dataframe for the user. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. here is my code. Around line 72 I could use help. I kept as much out as i could while keeping this functional, it is a large program, but this is my biggest problem so far. thank you

```
def main():
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from tabulate import tabulate

def parks():
    park_dict = {'Alaska': ['DENA', 'Denali National Park and Preserve', 'GAAR', 'Gates of the Arctic National Park', 'GLBA',
                   'Glacier Bay National Park', 'KATM', 'Katmai National Park and Preserve', 'KEFJ',
                   'Kenai Fjords National Park', 'KOVA', 'Kobuk Valley National Park', 'LACLk', 'Lake Clark National Park',
                   'WRST', 'Wrangell – St Elias National Park and Preserve'],
        'American_Samoa': ['NSPA', 'National Park of American Samoa','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Arizona': ['GRCA', 'Grand Canyon National Park', 'PEFO', 'Petrified Forest National Park', 'SAGU',
                    'Saguaro National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Arkansas': ['HOSP', 'Hot Springs National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'California': ['CHIS', 'Channel Islands National Park', 'DVNP', 'Death Valley National Park', 'JOTR',
                       'Joshua Tree National Park', 'KICA', 'Kings Canyon National Park', 'LAVO',
                       'Lassen Volcanic National Park', 'REDW', 'Redwood National Park', 'SEKI',
                       'Sequoia National Park', 'YOSE','Yosemite National Park'],
        'Caolorado': ['BLCA', 'Black Canyon of the Gunnison National Park', 'GRSA',
                      'Great Sand Dunes National Park and Preserve', 'MEVE', 'Mesa Verde National Park',
                      'ROMO','Rocky Mountain National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Florida': ['BISC', 'Biscayne National Park', 'DRTO', 'Dry Tortugas National Park', 'EVER',
                    'Everglades National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Hawaii': ['HALE', 'Haleakala National Park', 'HAVO', 'Hawaii Volcanoes National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Kentucky': ['MACA', 'Mammoth Cave National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Maine': ['ACAD', 'Acadia National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Michigan': ['ISRO', 'Isle Royale National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Minnesota': ['VOYA', 'Voyageurs National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Montana': ['GLAC', 'Glacier National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Nevada': ['GRBA', 'Great Basin National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'New_Mexico': ['CAVE', 'Carlsbad Caverns National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'North_Carolina': ['GRSM', 'Great Smoky Mountains National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'North_Dakota': ['THRO', 'Theodore Roosevelt National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Ohio': ['CUVA', 'Cuyahoga Valley National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Oregon': ['CRLA', 'Crater Lake National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'South_Carolina': ['COSW', 'Congaree National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'South_Dakota': ['BADL', 'Badlands National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Tennessee': ['GRSM', 'Great Smoky Mountains National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Texas': ['BIBE', 'Big Bend National Park', 'GUMO', 'Guadalupe Mountains National Park','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
        'US_Virgin_Islands': ['VIIS', 'Virgin Islands National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Utah': ['ARCH', 'Arches National Park', 'BRCA', 'Bryce Canyon National Park', 'CANY',
                 'Canyonlands National Park', 'CARE', 'Capitol Reef National Park', 'ZION', 'Zion National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Virginia': ['SHEN', 'Shenandoah National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Washington': ['MORA ', 'Mount Rainier National Park ', 'NOCA', 'North Cascades National Park', 'OLYM',
                       'Olympic National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'],
        'Wyoming': ['GRTE', 'Grand Teton National Park', 'YELL', 'Yellowstone National Park','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(park_dict)
    df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
    #print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple'))
    return''

def choose_state():
    state_list = [['AK', 'Alaska', 'AS', 'American Samoa', 'AZ', 'Arizona', 'AR', 'Arkansas'],
                  ['CA', 'California', 'CO', 'Colorado', 'FL', 'Florida', 'HI', 'Hawaii'],
                  ['KY', 'Kentucky', 'ME', 'Maine', 'MI', 'Michigan', 'MN', 'Minnesota'],
                  ['MT', 'Montana', 'NV', 'Nevada', 'NM', 'New Mexico', 'NC', 'North Carolina'],
                  ['ND', 'North Dakota', 'OH', 'Ohio', 'OR', 'Oregon', 'SC', 'South Carolina'],
                  ['SD', 'South Dakota', 'TN', 'Tennessee', 'TX', 'Texas', 'USVI', 'US Vergin Islands'],
                  ['UT', 'Utah', 'VA', 'Virginia', 'WA', 'Washington', 'WY', 'Wyoming']]

    statedf = pd.DataFrame(state_list, columns=['Abbr', 'State', 'Abbr', 'State', 'Abbr', 'State', 'Abbr', 'State'])
    print(tabulate(statedf, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple', showindex=False))
    while True:
        print('\nEnter the abreviation for the state you will visit\nR - Return tp previous menu\nQ - Quit')
        try:
            entry = str(input('\n').upper())
            if not entry.isalpha():
                print('please enter letters only.')
                choose_state()
                '''
                # if entry == (state abbr) in state_list, then take the full name of the state and look in (park_dict) and display the correct column)
                '''
                print(tabulate(park_dict, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple'))  # print correct column from park_dict

            elif entry == str('R'):
                choose_state()
            elif entry == str('Q'):
                print('Have a nice day.')
                exit()
            else:
                print('please enter 2 letter state abreviation.')
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid entry')
            choose_state()
            break
    return ''

def main_menu():
    print('Select choice from menu:\n\n'
          '1 - not ready\n'
          '2 - Select state and National Park you are visiting\n'
          '3 - Quit')

    while True:
        try:
            menu_choice = int(input('\n'))
            if menu_choice == int(1):
                print('ok')
                exit()
            elif menu_choice == int(2):
                choose_state()
                break
            elif menu_choice == int(3):
                print('Exiting program')
                exit()
            else:
                print('Value not recognized.')
                exit()
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid entry, please enter 1,2, or 3.')
            main_menu()
    return ''

print(main_menu())
```

main()

update:
I changed my code as MashodRana suggested below,and it definitely helped clean it up, but it is not working quite right.I keep getting attribute errors. I plan to take the dictionaries and have them just as csv files to help clean it up, but I think it should work.

these are the errors:
raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tabulate'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate
import csv



park_dict = {
    'Alaska': ['DENA', 'Denali National Park and Preserve', 'GAAR', 'Gates of the Arctic National Park', 'GLBA',
                   'Glacier Bay National Park', 'KATM', 'Katmai National Park and Preserve', 'KEFJ',
                   'Kenai Fjords National Park', 'KOVA', 'Kobuk Valley National Park', 'LACLk',
                   'Lake Clark National Park',
                   'WRST', 'Wrangell – St Elias National Park and Preserve'],
    'American_Samoa': ['NSPA', 'National Park of American Samoa', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                           '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Arizona': ['GRCA', 'Grand Canyon National Park', 'PEFO', 'Petrified Forest National Park', 'SAGU',
                    'Saguaro National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Arkansas': ['HOSP', 'Hot Springs National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                     '.', '.'],
    'California': ['CHIS', 'Channel Islands National Park', 'DVNP', 'Death Valley National Park', 'JOTR',
                       'Joshua Tree National Park', 'KICA', 'Kings Canyon National Park', 'LAVO',
                       'Lassen Volcanic National Park', 'REDW', 'Redwood National Park', 'SEKI',
                       'Sequoia National Park', 'YOSE', 'Yosemite National Park'],
    'Colorado': ['BLCA', 'Black Canyon of the Gunnison National Park', 'GRSA',
                      'Great Sand Dunes National Park and Preserve', 'MEVE', 'Mesa Verde National Park',
                      'ROMO', 'Rocky Mountain National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Florida': ['BISC', 'Biscayne National Park', 'DRTO', 'Dry Tortugas National Park', 'EVER',
                    'Everglades National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Hawaii': ['HALE', 'Haleakala National Park', 'HAVO', 'Hawaii Volcanoes National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                   '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Kentucky': ['MACA', 'Mammoth Cave National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                     '.', '.'],
    'Maine': ['ACAD', 'Acadia National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Michigan': ['ISRO', 'Isle Royale National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                     '.', '.'],
    'Minnesota': ['VOYA', 'Voyageurs National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                      '.', '.'],
    'Montana': ['GLAC', 'Glacier National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                    '.'],
    'Nevada': ['GRBA', 'Great Basin National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                   '.'],
    'New_Mexico': ['CAVE', 'Carlsbad Caverns National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                       '.', '.', '.'],
    'North_Carolina': ['GRSM', 'Great Smoky Mountains National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                           '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'North_Dakota': ['THRO', 'Theodore Roosevelt National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                         '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Ohio': ['CUVA', 'Cuyahoga Valley National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                 '.', '.'],
    'Oregon': ['CRLA', 'Crater Lake National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                   '.'],
    'South_Carolina': ['COSW', 'Congaree National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                           '.', '.'],
    'South_Dakota': ['BADL', 'Badlands National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                         '.', '.'],
    'Tennessee': ['GRSM', 'Great Smoky Mountains National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                      '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Texas': ['BIBE', 'Big Bend National Park', 'GUMO', 'Guadalupe Mountains National Park', '', '', '', '', '', '',
                  '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    'US_Virgin_Islands': ['VIIS', 'Virgin Islands National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                              '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Utah': ['ARCH', 'Arches National Park', 'BRCA', 'Bryce Canyon National Park', 'CANY',
                 'Canyonlands National Park', 'CARE', 'Capitol Reef National Park', 'ZION', 'Zion National Park', '.',
                 '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Virginia': ['SHEN', 'Shenandoah National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                     '.', '.'],
    'Washington': ['MORA ', 'Mount Rainier National Park ', 'NOCA', 'North Cascades National Park', 'OLYM',
                       'Olympic National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    'Wyoming': ['GRTE', 'Grand Teton National Park', 'YELL', 'Yellowstone National Park', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.',
                    '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']}
pdf = pd.DataFrame(park_dict)
pdf.index = np.arange(1, len(pdf) + 1)
#print(tabulate(pdf, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple'))
pdf.to_csv(r'park_dict.csv')



state_list = [['AK', 'Alaska', 'AS', 'American Samoa', 'AZ', 'Arizona', 'AR', 'Arkansas'],
                  ['CA', 'California', 'CO', 'Colorado', 'FL', 'Florida', 'HI', 'Hawaii'],
                  ['KY', 'Kentucky', 'ME', 'Maine', 'MI', 'Michigan', 'MN', 'Minnesota'],
                  ['MT', 'Montana', 'NV', 'Nevada', 'NM', 'New Mexico', 'NC', 'North Carolina'],
                  ['ND', 'North Dakota', 'OH', 'Ohio', 'OR', 'Oregon', 'SC', 'South Carolina'],
                  ['SD', 'South Dakota', 'TN', 'Tennessee', 'TX', 'Texas', 'USVI', 'US Virgin Islands'],
                  ['UT', 'Utah', 'VA', 'Virginia', 'WA', 'Washington', 'WY', 'Wyoming']]

sdf = pd.DataFrame(state_list, columns=['Abbr', 'State', 'Abbr', 'State', 'Abbr', 'State', 'Abbr', 'State'])
sdf = pd.DataFrame({'abbr': sdf['Abbr'].values.flatten(), 'state': sdf['State'].values.flatten()})
#sdf.to_csv(r'state_dict.csv')
#print(tabulate(sdf, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple', showindex=False))

def trail_finder():
    with open('AllTrails data.csv', 'r') as f:
        all_park_data = csv.reader(f)
        all_park_info = list(all_park_data)
#   print('\n'.join(' '.join(elems) for elems in all_park_info)) #just to verify data
    f.close()


def main():



    def choose_destination():
        print(tabulate(sdf, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple', showindex=False))
        # user input
        entry = str(input('Enter the abreviation for the state you will visit:\n').upper())
        while True:
            try:
                val = sdf[sdf['abbr'] == entry]
                state_name = val.values.flatten()[1]
                print(pd.tabulate(pdf))
                ndf = {state_name: pdf[state_name].values}
                print(tabulate(ndf, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple'))
                # error checking
                if not entry.isalpha():
                    print('please enter letters only.')
                else:
                    print('please enter 2 letter state abreviation.')
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid entry')
                break
        return ''

    def fitness_menu():
        print('1 - Determine fitness level\n2 - proceed to Trail Finder\n3 - Quit')
        while True:
            try:
                menu_choice = int(input('\n'))
                if menu_choice == int(1):
                    print('FIXME- build fitness level code')
                    break
                elif menu_choice == int(2):
                    choose_destination()
                    break
                elif menu_choice == int(3):
                    print('Exiting program')
                    exit()
                else:
                    print('Invalid entry, please enter 1, 2, or 3.')
                    exit()
            except ValueError:
                print(ValueError)
                exit()
        return ''


    def entrance_menu():

        print('Select choice from menu:\n\n'
            '1 - To use fitness calculator to determine fitness level(optional) \n'
            '2 - To choose destination\n'
            '3 - To Quit')

        while True:
            try:
                menu_choice = int(input('\n'))
                if menu_choice == int(1):
                    fitness_menu()
                    break
                elif menu_choice == int(2):
                    choose_destination()
                    break
                elif menu_choice == int(3):
                    print('Exiting program')
                    exit()
                else:
                    print('Invalid entry, please enter 1, 2, or 3.')
                    entrance_menu()
            except ValueError:
                print(ValueError)
                exit()
        return ''

    entrance_menu()


main()
```

Comment: I highly recommend looking up the "tidy data" concept to see how this problem can be looked at a bit differently: https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you are facing is due to your data being unstructured. To fix this, you should have your data organized like this instead, which is in a 'tidy' form [see here](https://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html)

```
STATE_DICT = {
    'state_name': {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AS': 'American Samoa',
        'AZ': 'Arizona',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'CA': 'California',
        'CO': 'Colorado',
        'FL': 'Florida',
        'HI': 'Hawaii',
        'KY': 'Kentucky',
        'ME': 'Maine',
        'MI': 'Michigan',
        'MN': 'Minnesota',
        'MT': 'Montana',
        'NV': 'Nevada',
        'NM': 'New Mexico',
        'NC': 'North Carolina',
        'ND': 'North Dakota',
        'OH': 'Ohio',
        'OR': 'Oregon',
        'SC': 'South Carolina',
        'SD': 'South Dakota',
        'TN': 'Tennessee',
        'TX': 'Texas',
        'USVI': 'US Vergin Islands',
        'UT': 'Utah',
        'VA': 'Virginia',
        'WA': 'Washington',
        'WY': 'Wyoming'}
}

PARKS_DICT = {
    'state_name': {
        'DENA': 'Alaska',
        'GAAR': 'Alaska',
        'GLBA': 'Alaska',
        'KATM': 'Alaska',
        'KEFJ': 'Alaska',
        'KOVA': 'Alaska',
        'LACLk': 'Alaska',
        'WRST': 'Alaska',
        'NSPA': 'American_Samoa',
        'GRCA': 'Arizona',
        'PEFO': 'Arizona',
        'SAGU': 'Arizona',
        'HOSP': 'Arkansas',
        'CHIS': 'California',
        'DVNP': 'California',
        'JOTR': 'California',
        'KICA': 'California',
        'LAVO': 'California',
        'REDW': 'California',
        'SEKI': 'California',
        'YOSE': 'California',
        'BLCA': 'Caolorado',
        'GRSA': 'Caolorado',
        'MEVE': 'Caolorado',
        'ROMO': 'Caolorado',
        'BISC': 'Florida',
        'DRTO': 'Florida',
        'EVER': 'Florida',
        'HALE': 'Hawaii',
        'HAVO': 'Hawaii',
        'MACA': 'Kentucky',
        'ACAD': 'Maine',
        'ISRO': 'Michigan',
        'VOYA': 'Minnesota',
        'GLAC': 'Montana',
        'GRBA': 'Nevada',
        'CAVE': 'New_Mexico',
        'GRSM': 'Tennessee',
        'THRO': 'North_Dakota',
        'CUVA': 'Ohio',
        'CRLA': 'Oregon',
        'COSW': 'South_Carolina',
        'BADL': 'South_Dakota',
        'BIBE': 'Texas',
        'GUMO': 'Texas',
        'VIIS': 'US_Virgin_Islands',
        'ARCH': 'Utah',
        'BRCA': 'Utah',
        'CANY': 'Utah',
        'CARE': 'Utah',
        'ZION': 'Utah',
        'SHEN': 'Virginia',
        'MORA': 'Washington',
        'NOCA': 'Washington',
        'OLYM': 'Washington',
        'GRTE': 'Wyoming',
        'YELL': 'Wyoming'},
    'park_name': {
        'DENA': 'Denali National Park and Preserve',
        'GAAR': 'Gates of the Arctic National Park',
        'GLBA': 'Glacier Bay National Park',
        'KATM': 'Katmai National Park and Preserve',
        'KEFJ': 'Kenai Fjords National Park',
        'KOVA': 'Kobuk Valley National Park',
        'LACLk': 'Lake Clark National Park',
        'WRST': 'Wrangell – St Elias National Park and Preserve',
        'NSPA': 'National Park of American Samoa',
        'GRCA': 'Grand Canyon National Park',
        'PEFO': 'Petrified Forest National Park',
        'SAGU': 'Saguaro National Park',
        'HOSP': 'Hot Springs National Park',
        'CHIS': 'Channel Islands National Park',
        'DVNP': 'Death Valley National Park',
        'JOTR': 'Joshua Tree National Park',
        'KICA': 'Kings Canyon National Park',
        'LAVO': 'Lassen Volcanic National Park',
        'REDW': 'Redwood National Park',
        'SEKI': 'Sequoia National Park',
        'YOSE': 'Yosemite National Park',
        'BLCA': 'Black Canyon of the Gunnison National Park',
        'GRSA': 'Great Sand Dunes National Park and Preserve',
        'MEVE': 'Mesa Verde National Park',
        'ROMO': 'Rocky Mountain National Park',
        'BISC': 'Biscayne National Park',
        'DRTO': 'Dry Tortugas National Park',
        'EVER': 'Everglades National Park',
        'HALE': 'Haleakala National Park',
        'HAVO': 'Hawaii Volcanoes National Park',
        'MACA': 'Mammoth Cave National Park',
        'ACAD': 'Acadia National Park',
        'ISRO': 'Isle Royale National Park',
        'VOYA': 'Voyageurs National Park',
        'GLAC': 'Glacier National Park',
        'GRBA': 'Great Basin National Park',
        'CAVE': 'Carlsbad Caverns National Park',
        'GRSM': 'Great Smoky Mountains National Park',
        'THRO': 'Theodore Roosevelt National Park',
        'CUVA': 'Cuyahoga Valley National Park',
        'CRLA': 'Crater Lake National Park',
        'COSW': 'Congaree National Park',
        'BADL': 'Badlands National Park',
        'BIBE': 'Big Bend National Park',
        'GUMO': 'Guadalupe Mountains National Park',
        'VIIS': 'Virgin Islands National Park',
        'ARCH': 'Arches National Park',
        'BRCA': 'Bryce Canyon National Park',
        'CANY': 'Canyonlands National Park',
        'CARE': 'Capitol Reef National Park',
        'ZION': 'Zion National Park',
        'SHEN': 'Shenandoah National Park',
        'MORA': 'Mount Rainier National Park',
        'NOCA': 'North Cascades National Park',
        'OLYM': 'Olympic National Park',
        'GRTE': 'Grand Teton National Park',
        'YELL': 'Yellowstone National Park'}
}
```

That way, you can easily query the data you are interested in as follows:

```
# make your dataframes:
states = pd.DataFrame(STATE_DICT).rename_axis('state_abbrev')
parks = pd.DataFrame(PARKS_DICT).rename_axis('park_abbrev')

# query
state_abbrev = input('enter state abbreviation: ')
state_name = states.loc[state_abbrev, 'state_name']
parks_list = parks.loc[parks.state_name == state_name]
```

or you can merge the tables together and lookup the state abbreviation directly:

```
df_joined = pd.merge(states.reset_index(), parks.reset_index(), on='state_name', how='inner')
parks_list = df_joined[df_joined.state_abbrev == state_abbrev]
```

This is how a database is organized which reduces redundancies and errors. Speaking of errors, it looks like you have inconsistent names for things that should all have the same name (i.e. 'Caolorado' instead of 'Colorado' or 'US_Virgin_Islands' and 'US Vergin Islands' rather than 'US Virgin Islands'). Arranging the data like this instead should help you mitigate those errors.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do your task in this way:**

Combine the all-states and abbreviations into a single column

```
sdf = pd.DataFrame({'abbr':statedf['Abbr'].values.flatten(),'state':statedf['State'].values.flatten()})
```

Search the abbreviations into the **sdf** (state data frame) and extract the corresponding full form

```
val = sdf[sdf['abbr']==entry]
state_name = val.values.flatten()[1]
```

Finally display the parks corresponding to state name from the **pdf**(park data frame)

```
ndf = {state_name:pdf[state_name].values}
print(tabulate(ndf, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple', showindex=False))
```

**Note:**
Please save your parks and state as CSV file. Then load them on your program. Don't use different columns for the same type of value like 'state' and 'abbreviation' And if you want you can improve your code in many ways.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I edited my post. I tried to incorporate the code you suggested, but am getting some errors. can you take a look and see if I entered something incorrectly. I am obviously pretty new to python, so any suggestions on how to improve my code would be appreciated. I will save the parks and state as csv, and the will likely not need the flatten.

Comment: I am sorry that I couldn't respond on time